# Adding custom cient-side form validations to Spree frontend

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-validate, spree

I am trying to add a custom, client-side validation to an input field in Spree's `checkout/address` page.
So, here is what I have done so far:

1. Add the input to the form (here using Haml & SimpleForm):

   ```
   = form.input :vat_number, label: Spree.t(:vat_number)
   ```
2. Inside my `vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/checkout/address.js.coffee`, add the jQuery validate method and insert the rule into the `validate()` call:

   ```
   ($).validator.addMethod "vatNumber", (value, element) -> 
     return false
   , "Something wrong!"

   Spree.onAddress = () ->
     if ($ '#checkout_form_address').is('*')

     ($ '#checkout_form_address').validate({
       rules: {
         order_bill_address_attributes_vat_number: {
           vatNumber: true
         }
       }
     })

     # ... rest of the file ...
   ```

The validator does not seem to operate on the `vat_number` field, although the remaining form validations work. In the `javascript` debug console, if I type `$.validator.methods`, I do see the new `vatNumber` method added in, so the problem must be either in the way I call `validate()`, or something to do with the fact that I am using `SimpleForm`.

I have changed the code around the `validate()` call to this:

```
($ '#order_bill_address_attributes_vat_number').rules("add", {vatNumber: true})
($ '#checkout_form_address').validate()
```

And I got the following error in the `javascript` console window:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.data(element.form,"validator").settings')
```

Has anyone tried to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.

Apparently, the `vatNumber` method was being added after the `Spree.onAddress` call on the bottom of the `address.js.coffee` file.

I moved the `addMethod` call to a different place (where I know it is called/run before the code in `address.js.coffee` and it suddenly worked.

Now, I wonder if this is a `CoffeeScript` thing. Could the order of the code change after the code is converted to `Javascript`?